# Issue in case of conflict in Git while committing the changes?

Tags: git

While pushing, I got a conflict. So I pulled it, and fixed the conflict in my local.

Git pull and push is not working.

For pull, the error is:

```
abc@xyz MINGW64 /e/Git project (master|MERGING)
 *git pull origin master*
error: You have not concluded your merge (MERGE_HEAD exists).
hint: Please, commit your changes before merging.
fatal: Exiting because of unfinished merge.
```

For push, error is:

```
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to center git repository
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
```

Comment: Read what the error message is telling you: `You have not concluded your merge (MERGE_HEAD exists).
hint: Please, commit your changes before merging.`.

Answer (score 0):

My first recommendation is verify the repository

```
git status
```

Then make the decision if you have resolved the conflict

```
git add files
git commit
```

Now you can push your changes, but it depends of your situation, please read https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging#Basic-Merge-Conflicts